# Intercepting or delegating events with overlapping components

Tags: java, swing, events, paintcomponent, miglayout

I have two `JPanels` equal in size, one over the top of the other. The top layer serves as a drag selection panel, and the other one has other components added to it. My problem is that the mouse event handlers of these added components aren't triggered, because they are handled by the overlaying panel instead. How can I still drag over the top of these added components, but still have `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited` enabled for the underlaying components?

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

As you can see, the selection rectangle is painted on the overlaying `JPanel`, but it's as if my mouse can't get through this panel to see what's underneath (in search of a better way to explain that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use an overlaying panel. I gave a suggestion in your last posting on how you might do this.

Or, if you do use an overlaying panel, then just use it for drawing and have the underlying panel listen for the mouse events and then invoke the repainting on the overlaying panel.

Edit:

Maybe a better approach is to use a MouseListener on the individual components and then to handle the drawing of the rectangle you can use a [Global Event Listener](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/) to listen for the mousePressed, mouseDragged, mouseReleased event. You would need to check the source of each event to see if the source was the panel itself oa component on the panel. You can use `SwingUtilities.isDescendingFrom(...)` to help with this second test.

Comment: The problem with that was that I couldn't drag from within one of the components. Having the mouse events handled by the overlaying panel means I can drag from within the colored blocks. I'll check your other suggestion.

Comment: Okay, overriding `paint` works, but still: "`The problem with that was that I couldn't drag from within one of the components.`"

Comment: Don't add MouseListeners to the other components then the mouse event should be passed to the panel.

Comment: But what if I require them? I need `mouseClicked` and rollover / `mouseEntered` / `mouseExited`.

Comment: I could check to see if any of the components contains the mouse `Point`?

Comment: I like this very much. I'll have to read up a bit on exactly how it works but from what I've read in your tutorial it seems like a good way to go about it. Thanks, Rob. :)

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to re-inventing the wheel is using JLayer (new to jdk7, available for jdk6 in the [SwingLabs subproject JXLayer](http://jxlayer.java.net)):

> JLayer is a universal decorator for Swing components which enables you
>   to implement various advanced painting effects as well as receive
>   notifications of all AWTEvents generated within its borders

Below is a quick example - just to demonstrate its usage, logic obviously incomplete :) - of spanning a rubberband with mouseEvents

```
// UI which allows to span a rubberband on top of the component
public static class RubberBandUI<V extends JComponent> extends LayerUI<V> {
    private JLayer<?> l;
    private Rectangle rubberband;
    private boolean selecting;

    @Override
    public void installUI(JComponent c) {
        super.installUI(c);
        l = (JLayer<?>) c;
        // this LayerUI will receive mouse/motion events
        l.setLayerEventMask(AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK | AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK);
     }

     @Override
    public void uninstallUI(JComponent c) {
        super.uninstallUI(c);
        // JLayer must be returned to its initial state
        l.setLayerEventMask(0);
        l = null;
     }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent l) {
        // this paints layer as is
        super.paint(g, l);
        if (rubberband == null) return;
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        // custom painting is here
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2f));
        g2.draw(rubberband);
    }

    // intercept events as appropriate 

    @Override
    protected void processMouseMotionEvent(MouseEvent e, JLayer<? extends V> l) {
        super.processMouseMotionEvent(e, l);
        if (e.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED && selecting) {
            Point point = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(e.getComponent(), e.getPoint(), l);
            adjustRubberband(point);
            l.repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e, JLayer<? extends V> l) {
        super.processMouseEvent(e, l);
        if (e.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED) {
            endRubberband();
        }
        if (e.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED && e.getSource() == l) {
            startRubberband(e.getPoint());
        }
    }

    // logic to start/stop/adjust the rubberband 
    private void adjustRubberband(Point point) {
        // logic to span the rubberband
        int width = point.x - rubberband.x;
        int height = point.y - rubberband.y;
        rubberband.setSize(width, height);
    }

    private void startRubberband(Point p) {
        rubberband = new Rectangle(p);
        selecting = true;
        // block events to child components while drawing
        l.getGlassPane().setVisible(true);
        l.repaint();
    }

    private void endRubberband() {
        selecting = false;
        l.getGlassPane().setVisible(false);
        l.repaint();
    }

    public void clear() {
        rubberband = null;
        l.repaint();
    }
}
```

Sample usage snippet:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    panel.add(new JButton("JButton"));
    panel.add(new JCheckBox("JCheckBox"));
    panel.add(new JTextField("JTextField"));
}
JLayer<JComponent> l = new JLayer<JComponent>(panel, new RubberBandUI<JComponent>());
frame.add(l);
```

Comment: are you meaning this https://svn.java.net/svn/jxlayer~svn/trunk/src/java/org/jdesktop/jxlayer/JXLayer.java by Alex, or am I wrong

Comment: @mKorbel yeah, that's the version for jdk6

Comment: then I saw (not able to re_testing and I'm un_install Java7 because ice_bear with that) difference between stable version by Alex and implemented Woodoo in Java7, btw in this case Robs comp mover and resizer could be better and easiest options ...

Comment: @mKorbel the api difference between the two is minimal, in fact the example is a quick adjustment to jdk7 of the MouseDrawingDemo in JXLayer. You certainly do not expect me to not disagree with using single classes - as nice as they are if nothing else is available - vs. stable and tested frameworks in SwingLabs :-)