# Possible to layer ImageIcons?

Tags: java, swing, gif, imageicon

I was wondering if it were possible to layer ImageIcons in Java. I will be working with GIF images, and will have a grid of ImageIcons representing the "background" of my JPane.

When a certain condition is true, I need to be able to add an image that has transparency on top of the other image.

Regards,
Jack Hunt

Comment: as you see from the answers: many ways to Rome :-) Which to choose, depends on the exact requirements in your context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes that's possible and there are two correct ways

1) if is there only one Image then put [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) with [Icon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) to the [GlassPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html)

2) use [LayeredPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) for <= Java6 (not Java7 user there is JLayer)

Comment: +1, but what is *incorrect* about a) the answers of paranoid-android & trashgod. b) rendering the entire lot to a single `BufferedImage` that is added to a label and updated when needed?  It seems there are a lot of ways to skin this cat.  ;)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson even all that you deleted your answer interesting idea, pleeeeeeeeeeeeeeaaaaaaaaaaase example for that

Comment: I decided to delete it when I saw PA's better description of the same idea.  As to example code, I avoided it since there are so many 'near variants' of this across SO ( and I really should be doing other things ;).

Comment: Or did you mean an example of 'b'?

Comment: @AndrewThompson that's a really good idea. Effectively taking a snapshot whenever the background is updated. I think it depends on how often (or how) the background will be changing. If it changes rapidly, there wouldn't be much point. Hardly, then yes it would be ideal. :) +1.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson I have strong bases (your code) http://stackoverflow.com/a/7944388/714968, and untill now I never saw whatever, sure this code missed overlaying, there is only about to replace for Icon/ImageIcon on some period

Comment: +1 for `JLayeredPane`, but I've not tried it with `AlphaComposite`.

Comment: @trashgod I've always found `JLayeredPane` to be a nightmare. For some reason I prefer painting to adding. No idea why. And `AlphaComposite` seems unnecessary seeing as the gif is translucent and the `JLabel`'s opacity would be false by default. What would `AlphaComposite` be used for?

Comment: @paranoid-android AlphaComposite is same as impression of the suggesstion by (@AndrewThompson)

Comment: @all seems like as (@paranoid-android) maybe you ignored one of the answers to your very similair question by (@kleopatra)  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8787294/714968, on bottom is sticked link to code_soouce for JLayer in Java6

Comment: @mKorbel I did read that answer some time ago, though I'm not familiar with `jdk7 / JXLayer` etc. so even though it was a very good answer, my entire application is in `jdk6 Swing` so I will stick to it for now. Next project -> Java 7.

Comment: BTW: glassPane is a per-rootpane notion, not per-panel - so most probably rather useless here (apart from its hard-to-handle characteristics ..)

Comment: @kleopatra could be confortable in case that Image / Icon / ImageIcon is dragged from somewhere for overlaying effects (animations / sliding / bluring)

Comment: @paranoid-android: Opacity and transparency are not the same, as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3518047/230513). The default mode, clarified [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9227314/230513), may be sufficient.

Comment: @trashgod I'm very well aware of that. My suggestion was the use `JLabel` or `JComponent` which is already for all intents and purposes 'transparent', but because gif's don't support translucency, I suggested to use png instead, which should take care of any 'transparency' issues.

Comment: @paranoid-android: Ah, I confounded GIF's _transparency_ with composite _translucency_.

Answer (score 5):

You could simply use `g.drawImage(...)` to draw them onto the panel in an overriden `paintComponent` method. That would be the easiest way to do that.

Because your question mentions `ImageIcon`, it would be correct to use it if your gif's are animated. Otherwise, `BufferedImage` is generally preferred. If you decide to keep to `ImageIcon`, you should use `paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y)` instead of `g.drawImage(...)`.

If you want to add images dynamically, consider storing them in an array or `ArrayList`, then simply iterate through the array / list in your `paintComponent`.

For example:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(){
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
       super.paintComponent(g);
       if(yourCondition){
           g.drawImage(img, x, y, this); // for example.
       }
    }
};
```

The other alternative is to create a private class which extends JPanel.
For example:

```
public class OuterClass{
    // fields, constructors, methods etc..

    private class MyPanel extends JPanel{   
       // fields, constructors, methods etc..

       @Override
       public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
          super.paintComponent(g);
          if(yourCondition){
             g.drawImage(img, x, y, this); // for example.
          }
       }

    }
}
```

Side note: Any particular reason why you need to use GIF? PNG is generally better.

**EDIT:** (according to Andrew Thompson's idea)

In order to take a snapshot of all the images contained in the background...
A variant of the following idea:

```
BufferedImage background;

public void captureBackground(){
    BufferedImage img = GraphicsConfiguration.createCompatibleImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
    for(ImageIcon i : imageIconArray){ // could be for(BufferedImage i : imageArray){
         i.paintIcon(this, g, 0, 0);   // g.drawImage(i, 0, 0, null);
    }
    g.dispose();
    background = img;
    // either paint 'background' or add it to your background panel here.
}
```

Comment: +1 I'm inclined to prefer `JLayeredPane`, but I _know_ this works with  `AlphaComposite`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the modes of [`AlphaComposite`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AlphaComposite.html) to achieve a variety of effects. There's an example and utility [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/composite).

Addendum: Note that the default composite mode for a platform's concrete implementation of [`Graphics2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) is [`AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AlphaComposite.html#SRC_OVER), which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [Overlay Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/26/overlap-layout/) to stack JLabels on top of one another.

Or you could use the [Compound Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/compound-icon/) to stack icons on top of one another.